# Laravel 5.4 queues storing the data in jobs table but not sending the queues emails on server

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, laravel-5, queue

For Laravel Queue to run in background i have installed supervisor on Ubuntu so that i can run queue:work command on Ubuntu as a service 24 h so that i can send emails to user using email Queue.

for that i have created a file a file in

> /etc/supervisor/conf.d

to monitor the  process **queue:work**.

here is my file

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/laravel/artisan queue:work database --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=ubuntu
numprocs=4
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/laravel/storage/logs/laravel-worker.log
```

and here is my laravel Mail Queue code

```
Mail::to($email)->queue(new SubscriberEmail($name));
```

when i run this code the laravel store the data in **jobs table** but don't send the emails to users

i have also checked the **failed jobs** table but their is no data in that table.

i have run this command on server

```
sudo supervisorctl status
```

it shows me this detail

> laravel-worker:laravel-worker_00   FATAL     Exited too quickly
>   (process log may have details)
>
> laravel-worker:laravel-worker_01   FATAL     Exited too quickly
>   (process log may have details)
>
> laravel-worker:laravel-worker_02   FATAL     Exited too quickly
>   (process log may have details)
>
> laravel-worker:laravel-worker_03   FATAL     Exited too quickly
>   (process log may have details)

i have gone to logs folder but their no log file has been generated.

Kindly help me on this issue please.

Thanks